# Including descriptive statistics as regressor in a panel model

Tags: interaction, panel-data, standard-deviation

I have panel data and believe that independent variable X drives changes in Y. However, my hypothesis is that the relationship between X and Y is modified by the volatility of X.

Generally speaking, how should I model this? Can I simply interact continuous variable X with its standard deviation? Obviously, the standard deviation only varies across panel unit and not over time.

Thanks!